# document.referrer.indexOf() breaking in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

The function below is breaking at the first `if` statement in IE8. I'm not sure what would cause this since from what I have researched none of this should cause an issue. I also tried adding the `toLowerCase()` method after the `referrer` property as well, still no luck. Any ideas?

```
function returnToLogin() {
    if (document.referrer.indexOf('attendant_login') > 0) {
        if (thisevent == null) {
            window.location = document.referrer;
        } else {
            setTimeout(returnToLogin, 1000);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Define "breaking" for us. Does the console in the web dev tools have any errors? You might have to click "Start debugging" (I think it's in the Script tab) to see something useful.

Comment: Step 1: log `document.referrer` at that point. =)

Comment: No errors display in the console. I added log statements immediately before and after the if statement that would print out the thisevent var. The first log statement showed as expected the second did not. Both showed fine in modern browsers.

Comment: Is this a crucial part of your application? If so, you need to rethink how that should work, because referrers just aren’t reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE doesn't always set the `document.referrer` property. The solution is to check if it is defined before calling methods on it. Change your `if` to:

```
if (document.referrer&&document.referrer.indexOf('attendant_login') > 0) {
```

Now if `document.referrer` doesn't exist, it won't try to call the `indexOf` method on it, so it won't break. Instead it will just behave as though the test failed (which I imagine is a suitable default)

Comment: @Stavros_S did you use the code exactly as posted? Maybe you only used a single `&`? There's no reason for this code to fail that I can see (although I don't have IE to test on)

Comment: Yup exactly as such, it's not making much sense to me either at the moment.

Comment: All I can suggest is adding `if(document.referrer)alert(document.referrer);` to try to debug what's going on. The only possibilities I can think of are: the referrer object is somehow something other than a string or null/undefined, it's a very very bizarre behaviour in IE8 (unlikely even for IE), it's switched to a new error on a different line, or the code you're running isn't what you posted.

Comment: I actually did alert it out and as expected it returned nothing but an empty alert box. I'm really hoping I can figure out why your way isn't working since I really want to avoid browser sniffing.

Comment: Try this instead: `if (document.referrer != null && document.referrer.indexOf('attendant_login') > 0) {`

Comment: Please run this jsfiddle and/or put the code in your page which has the problem, and tell me what gets printed and if there are any errors: http://jsfiddle.net/tE7gL/ (also, the code that bastos suggested is functionally identical to what I posted; it will behave the same)

Answer (score 1):

document.referrer which you used will return requesting page URL for all browsers except for Internet Explorer, in [some cases](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.pt/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html) it actually returns null in the IE.

Answer (score -1):

IE has problems with using `Array.indexOf()`. Use  `jQuery.inArray()` instead.

Comment: Now, the `referer` url is a string.

Comment: It is true that [`Array.indexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679977(v=vs.94).aspx) doesn't exist in IE8 and below, but as Bergi pointed out, [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) is a string, and [`String.indexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx) is supported down to at least IE6.

Comment: The example I posted is also not using JQuery but rather vanilla JS.